# GA4 - Trying to Link Search Console Account - "Product Links" section does not appear under "Property Column", How can I fix this?

Tags: google-analytics-4, google-search-console

I have been trying to connect my Google Search Console account to my GA4 account. All instructions are very straightforward:

GA4 > Admin > Property Column > Scroll to Product Links > Add Search Console

The issue is that the "Product Links" section does not exist in my account, I cannot find it.  I have been searching everywhere and even Google's own documentation does not have a solution for this. Am I missing something? Is there a setting I have turned off? What's going on here?

Any help appreciated, thanks!